# Better UI for exchanging blocks up and down

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, hci, code

I have developed a UI as shown below:

[image]

Now I want to add a functionality to this UI that if user wants to exchange positions of `if` and `else if` blocks, he must be able to do that.

One option could be an up and down arrow icon next to each if and else if, to move the blocks up and down. What could be other better options?

Comment: Can an `else if` block be the first block? Otherwise, why would there be a need to move `if` blocks? (assuming that there only can be one, as the button only allows to create new `else if` blocks)

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest adding drag handles on each block and let the user decide the ordering. You'll only need to ensure that no matter the order of blocks, the first block will always be an `if` block and the remaining blocks- `else if`.

Refer the image for more details

[image]

This way the user will come to know upfront that the blocks are drag-able, both on desktop as well as mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

All other answers suggest **drag** handles, but I suggest **against** that.

The problem with drag handles is that:

- you ask the user to move a block from one position to a *specific* area. If he misses the area, errors can easily occur.
- if the block you're moving is too high, the travel distance can become cumbersome.
- it can be hard to implement
- drag handles suggest that the item can be moved anywhere, but in this case, there's only one target

Drag handles work well with a **list** of **N** items, where each of these item take up a small amount of space, and where each item could be moved **anywhere** within the list.

### Switch, not drag

Here, you just want to **switch** positions, between **2** items. There is only 1 start position, and 1 target position. Just use a toggle button.

### Examples

For example, Google Translate uses a double-arrow button to toggle between the source language and the destination language:

[image]

Here's Converbot:

[image]

### Keep it simple

Don't give your users the illusion that can they can move items around anywhere with drag handles. Just have a single button that performs the single action of switching positions.

Comment: What if you have 10 else if's and you need to add another one, but this one needs to be placed at the top (for some reason). The screenshot suggests blocks can only be added at the bottom. In your case you'll have to press switch button 10 times. Dragging can also be done in grids, minimizing the chance for errors. You can even constrain movement to just the Y axis.

Comment: You're right. In *that* case, it would definitely make *more* sense to have some kind of drag behavior. But still, you would need to come up with a more **condensed** interface. If you have 10 of these blocks, you'll have to drag **and** scroll the page at the same time. Dragging works for example in GMail, because each email takes up 20-30 pixels in height. So, when dragging, you can see both the *start* point and the *destination* area.

Comment: Collapsable blocks?

Comment: @Paul Spreadsheets software usually have a button "insert before current row". You could imagine having **N** `add` buttons instead of just one, and the problem doesn't exist any more.

Comment: I am of the same opinion as @Paul !

Comment: [My answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53028/40110) didn't have drag handles, just FYI

Answer (score 3):

Mailchimp uses and icon to indicate the draggability of the block.

[image]

Google uses drag handles in Gmail, they appear on hover.

[image]

Using an icon (any icon) or drag handles to indicate the object is draggable are both good solutions, but it all comes down to the affordance of the solutions. When showing it to your user, will they understand it's meaning? One way of solving that is by introducing the feature to new users. Which one to choose is up to you.

A third option is to set the cursor property to `move` on hover. This is by default a good thing to do and can be used in combination with the previous options. One note of advice with that is to only make part of the block draggable (just a handle) so users won't see the move cursor all the time when moving over the blocks. They still have to select and click stuff on the blocks. The move cursor might make the user believe they can't select the drop down boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to solve this problem, I would have combined two different ways to do it :

- Enabling the user to drag blocks to change their position.
- When one block is selected, using the arrows of the keyboard to change their position.

I think that it's interesting to combine different ways to do something, so you could also display the arrows you was speaking about on hover or if the block is selected although I don't think that this way to do it is as natural as dragging or using the keyboard.

Comment: I've noticed that you leave an 'im french' disclaimer on every answer. This is just noise on the answer and is not required. If there are grammar errors, we can usually tell you are not a native English speaker and _that is OK!_ No apology is necessary :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gusdor ! I was in fact wondering if you guys could tell that I wasn't english or If you would have thought that I was a stupid guy who wouldn't know how to speak his own language ! Thanks again for your answer, I won't put that anymore then...

Comment: You are welcome. Your English is great btw. Errors are only a problem if it can't be understood - in that case some _will_ ask you to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

When I do lists of orderable elements, I try to avoid drag handles but only becuase *they are fiddly with smaller UI elements* in my case.

Instead I implement `Move Up` and `Move Down` buttons on buttons or a context area (or both).

The downside of directly replacing drag handles with buttons is that the user needs to reposition the mouse after each *move* action. Ideally, you want a selection mechanism to highlight (or 'check') the block(s) being moved and static buttons that appear when a block is selected.

[image]

Related buttons could also include `Remove`, `Add Comment`, `Copy`. A drag handle does not let you naturally add these actions in the same mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as you suggested and use ***up / down arrows*** on the ***if blocks*** as well as the ***individual conditions*** in case the user wanted to swap any of those as well.

You can also make the arrows aware of their position by enabling / disabling them based on whether they can move their item up or down or not.

Based on your image, here's what it could look like:

[image]

> ***Note:***
> Obviously, you could give the individual conditions a little more height so you can have larger arrows.